# Failed to load config "next/core-web-vitals" to extend from

Tags: typescript, next.js

If you start new project on NextJs, TS. You can see this error

```
Failed to load config "next/core-web-vitals" to extend from.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried different variants and this help me.

```
//.eslintrs.json
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```